# Is possible to avoid this Exception in System.dll in a Portable library from .net to uwp?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, portable-class-library

I am so new in .netcore and somethings are new for me. 
I have a dll with this characteristics:

```
**[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows=true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("XXX")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("XXX")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright \xxx 2017 XXX")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("XXXXXX.Services.XXXX.Desktop")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4.6.1")]**
```

I am trying to publish some of the functions of this library in a portable library for .netcore.

My portable library compiles perfectly adding that library. As soon as I execute it from UWP app I receive an exception( below).
This dll has some dependencies on the library System.xml with the PublicKeyToken that appears in the exception below.

*Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"*

Am I doing something wrong?There is any way to solve this? I do not have access to the main dll code.

My portable class is so simple:

```
using XXXXX.Services.XXXX.Desktop;
namespace RobAPIDesktop
{
    public static class RobAPiPortable
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {

                DesktopInit.Initialize();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a .net standard 2.0 library?   That would work better that a pcl

Comment: After taking a look I think you are right. Anyway I get other erros like  'System.AggregateException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll but that other thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCLs are dead. You should be using .NET Standard library.

Take a look at the matrix on this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

If you create netstandard 2.0 library, you get access to a much larger set of APIs but the min version of UWP platform that can consume that library is 10.0.16299.

You need to find the sweet spot between which APIs you need, select the lowest netstandard version which has those APIs, and that'll make your library accessible to larger audience. So, if netstandard 1.4 has all the APIs you need, then it can be consumed by any UWP project.